# Identifying a power series

Tags: power-series

I'm no analyst, so when a student in the class to whom I was teaching some elementary theory of (power) series, asked about this:

$\displaystyle{\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n^n}=1+x+\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{x}{3}\right)^3+\left(\frac{x}{4}\right)^4+\cdots}$

(assuming $0^0=1$), I had no idea.  It didn't look like anything I recognized, and a play about with some derivatives gave me no useful information.

Is this a known function, and does this series admit of an explicit formula?

Comment: You can calculate a good value at $x=1,$ say, and put the decimal digits at http://oeis.org/search?q=7%2C1%2C8%2C2%2C8%2C1%2C8%2C2%2C8&language=english&go=Search  or put as a real number at http://isc.carma.newcastle.edu.au/standard or http://isc.carma.newcastle.edu.au/advanced

Comment: Yep, I already tried that (putting the digits of x=1 into OEIS), and got returned that it was the value of the sum of 1/n^n from 0 to infinity.  The inverse symbolic calculator at newcastle gives the same.

Comment: That suggests that this function has no name of its own....Also, you don't come across entire functions that often. Modular functions,  what have you, typically meromorphic or worse; just not that common to study something with infinite radius of convergence other than $e^z$

Comment: Talking about useful information, did you determine the Interval of Convergence? That is doable with the root test, I believe

Comment: @imranfat Each coefficient is much, much smaller than the corresponding coefficient of $e^x$. Thus this converges everywhere, very quickly.

Comment: probably something to be learned from the reference books for http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entire_function although the only similar series displayed is not given a name.

Comment: This power series does have a real root at $x\approx-1.403761051217752$. Needless to say, all real roots are necessarily negative...but I think this is the only **real** root.

Answer (score 1):

To start analyzing this series, you could consider using Sterling's approximation $n!\approx \left(\frac ne\right)^n\sqrt {2\pi n}$:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac xn\right)^n\approx \sqrt{2\pi}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac {\sqrt n({x\over e})^n}{n!}\ge \sqrt{2\pi}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac {({x\over e})^n}{n!}=e^{\frac xe} \sqrt{2\pi}$$

Of course this is only a lower limit to the approximated value, and that $\sqrt n$ term still needs to be dealt with...

Answer (score 0):

I had to do a lot of research on this, which was my benefit :)

**Outline.** Basically, I will use the [Sophomore's Dream](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore%27s_dream) to deduce an integral expression for the answer.

**Lemma.** We see
$$\int^{1}_{0}x^{n}\ln(x)^{n}\,\mathrm{d}x = (-1)^{n}(n+1)^{-(n+1)}n!\tag{1}$$

*Proof.* We change variables writing
$$\tag{2a}x=\exp\bigl(-u/(n+1)\bigr)$$
which lets us rewrite (1) as
$$\int^{1}_{0}x^{n}\ln(x)^{n}\,\mathrm{d}x = (-1)^{n}(n+1)^{-(n+1)}\int^{\infty}_{0}u^{n}e^{-u}\,\mathrm{d}u\tag{2b}$$
Observe the integral on the right hand side is precisely $n!$ (thanks to the Gamma function). And that concludes the proof for our lemma. QED.

**Theorem.** We claim
$$f(t) = 1+\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\left(\frac{t}{n}\right)^{n} = 1 + t\int^{1}_{0}x^{-xt}\,\mathrm{d}x.\tag{3}$$

*Proof.* We end up rewriting the integrand on the right hand side
$$x^{-xt} = e^{-xt\ln(x)} = \sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\frac{(-t)^{n}}{n!}x^{n}\ln(x)^{n}.\tag{4a}$$
We plug this back into the integral
$$\int^{1}_{0}x^{-xt}\,\mathrm{d}x= \int^{1}_{0}\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\frac{(-t)^{n}}{n!}x^{n}\ln(x)^{n}\,\mathrm{d}x.\tag{4b}$$
Swap the sum and integral
$$\int^{1}_{0}\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\frac{(-t)^{n}}{n!}x^{n}\ln(x)^{n}\,\mathrm{d}x
=\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\frac{(-t)^{n}}{n!}\int^{1}_{0}x^{n}\ln(x)^{n}\,\mathrm{d}x.\tag{4c}$$
We use our lemma to rewrite the right hand side as
\begin{align}
\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\frac{(-t)^{n}}{n!}\int^{1}_{0}x^{n}\ln(x)^{n}\,\mathrm{d}x &= \sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\frac{(-t)^{n}}{n!}\left((-1)^{n}(n+1)^{-n+1}n!\right)\\
&= \sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\frac{t^{n}}{(n+1)^{n+1}}.\tag{4c}
\end{align}
Then we just fiddle with arithmetic (multiply by $t$, and add 1) to get the series in question. That concludes our proof for the theorem. QED.

*Remark.* There is no closed form expression for the integral that I am aware of. Perhaps either the OP or some other user knows some fancy-pants way to evaluate the integral, but I do not know of one readily available :(